# Playsound only plays the mp3 file once and then gives the error "Permission Denied"

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder, gtts, python-playsound

I am using **Playsound** and **gtts** in **Spyder** IDE which creates an **mp3** file and then plays it.

```
import gtts
from playsound import playsound
#pass text to gTTS object 

# make request to google to get synthesis
english = gtts.gTTS("Hello world") #retrieved the actual audio speech from the API

# save the audio file
english.save("hello.mp3")
# play the audio file
playsound("hello.mp3")
```

It plays fine the first time but then shows this every time I run it:

```
  File "C:\Users\ASUS\.spyder-py3\all codes\Text2Speech.py", line 27, in <module>
    english.save("hello.mp3")

  File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 312, in save
    with open(str(savefile), 'wb') as f:

  PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'hello.mp3'
```

It works fine again after I restart Spyder, then again doesn't work after playing only once. My OS is Windows 10, **Playsound version 1.2.2**

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the full traceback, but my guess is that `playsound` isn't closing the file handle, so `english.save` fails next time.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I just added more lines to the traceback section. 

If it is happening because `playsound` isn't closing, how to solve that issue?

Comment: The first time you run the code you get the output

    `Error 263 for command:
        close hello.mp3
    Device is not open or not recognized by MCI.
    Failed to close the file: hello.mp3`

which indicates that playsound didn't close the file. Thus, next time, GTTS can't write to it any more.

My personal experience is that `playsound` is not a mature library. It does all kind of external stuff that it has no real control over.

Comment: I also can't recommend `pydub` because it needs a copy of FFMPEG to be installed.
I also can't recommend `Mpg123` because it needs libmpg123 to be installed.
I had no problems with `pygame` before, but it can't play the MP3 files of GTTS. Yeah, playing sound with Python really sucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is a bit old but I'll leave this here just in case anyone else struggles with it.

I had a similar problem with my code, I was building a voice assistant that uses input from your microphone then speaks back to you using gTTS and playsound. It would only work once then after the mp3 file is created, it can no longer be used again with a second voice command.

The solution I found was either giving the file a different name every single time you create it (which would create a mess in most cases), or deleting the file after it is used.

Here is what my "speak" function looks like, it just saves the text to sound translation into an mp3 file then plays it. At the end I added `os.remove(file_path)` with `file_path` being the file name itself or the path to it.

```py
def speak(text):
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang="en")
    filename = "voice.mp3"
    tts.save(filename)
    playsound.playsound(filename)
    os.remove("voice.mp3")
```

This solution only works if this specific mp3 file is being used by the program to "speak" back to you, since it rarely ever needs to go back to what it said before, the file is temporary and deleting it doesn't do any harm.